# Remove unwanted texts from a string

Tags: dart

i want to remove unwanted texts in a string in dart

String s=[:en]some[:ml]thing[:];

how to get some thing in s.

I tryed  using replaceAll() function but it take too much lines

Comment: Please provides some examples of strings and the expected output after removing the parts you don't want. Right now, it is rather unclear what you want to get removed, what you have tried and what problem you have.

Comment: string is '[:en]some[:ml]thing[:]'   and expected out put is 'some thing'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you have already tried but you can do something like this using a regular expression together with `replaceAll`:

```
void main() {
  final input = '[:en]some[:ml]thing[:]';
  final output = input.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\[.*?\]'), '');
  print(output); // something
}
```